# Pyspark - Get remaining value of column which is not present in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with columns `first_name` and `forenames`. `first_name` has first string of characters before the first space or if hyphen occurs in first string of characters prior to first space within forenames.

```
|forenames        | first_name |
+--------+---------------------+
|IVO KAI ROGERS   |  IVO       |
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|  DYLAN     |
|JOSH JACK        |  JOSH      |
|MONALISA ELIEN   |  MONALISA  |
|RACHEL-GREEN JOE |RACHEL-GREEN|
```

I want to create a new column `middle_name` which will have second string of characters from `forenames` after the first space followed by `first_name`.
Expected Output will be:

```
|forenames        | first_name | middle_name |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|IVO KAI ROGERS   |  IVO       | KAI ROGERS  |
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|  DYLAN     | STUART JOHN |
|JOSH JACK        |  JOSH      | JACK        |
|MONALISA ELIEN   |  MONALISA  | ELIEN       |
|RACHEL-GREEN JOE |RACHEL-GREEN| JOE         |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `replace` function using `expr`.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('IVO KAI ROGERS','IVO'),('RACHEL-GREEN JOE','RACHEL-GREEN')],['forenames','firstname'])
df.show(10,False)

+----------------+------------+
#|forenames       |firstname   |
#+----------------+------------+
#|IVO KAI ROGERS  |IVO         |
#|RACHEL-GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN|
#+----------------+------------+
df.selectExpr("*","replace(forenames,firstname) as middlename").show(10,False)
#+----------------+------------+-----------+
#|forenames       |firstname   |middlename |
#+----------------+------------+-----------+
#|IVO KAI ROGERS  |IVO         | KAI ROGERS|
#|RACHEL-GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN| JOE       |
#+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

There are two ways we can approach here, by using regexp_replace, replace functions.

```
#using regexp_replace
df = spark.createDataFrame([('IVO KAI ROGERS','IVO'),('RACHEL- GREEN JOE','RACHEL-\\s+GREEN')],['forenames','firstname'])
df.show(10,False)
df.selectExpr("*","regexp_replace(forenames,firstname,'') as middlename").show(10,False)

#using replace
df = spark.createDataFrame([('IVO KAI ROGERS','IVO'),('RACHEL- GREEN JOE','RACHEL-GREEN')],['forenames','firstname'])
df.show(10,False)
df.selectExpr("*","replace(forenames,replace(firstname,'-','- ')) as middlename").show(10,False)

#+-----------------+------------+
#|forenames        |firstname   |
#+-----------------+------------+
#|IVO KAI ROGERS   |IVO         |
#|RACHEL- GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN|
#+-----------------+------------+
#
#+-----------------+------------+-----------+
#|forenames        |firstname   |middlename |
#+-----------------+------------+-----------+
#|IVO KAI ROGERS   |IVO         | KAI ROGERS|
#|RACHEL- GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN| JOE       |
#+-----------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. But for this scenario:  ``` |forenames       | first_name | middle_name    |
|RACHEL- GREEN JOE |RACHEL-GREEN|RACHEL- GREEN JOE| ``` It doesn't give me correct output

Comment: check my updated answer, it works for this case too..!

Comment: The `forenames` has a value `RACHEL- GREEN JOE` (there's a space after hyphen). If there's no space after hyphen it work's fine. With space it gives whole value in middlename

Comment: IT works for above scenario -when we have space after hyphen but there are other cases where we don't have space after hyphen. Ex: `IVO-VI KAI ROGERS` which gives me output as: `IVO-VI KAI ROGERS`, though I should be getting `KAI ROGERS` as middlename.

Comment: @MuskanMakhija, please keep in mind that every time you should expect an answer only for the initial question not for every problem you face during the development process. Also don't forget to mark it as solved if you received an valid answer..!